# Getting Error "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)" when trying to run a Qt application on Windows server 2012

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I have developed an application on my laptop (Windows 7, 64-bit) using Qt 5.4.1 MSVC2013 64bit. The compiler used is Microsoft Visual C++ compiler 12.0 (amd64). I built the application in Release mode, copied all the required dll files into the release directory, and copied the whole directory over to the server where the application will be running. On trying to run the application in the server, I get the error message "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)". In the problem details pane, the fault module is "ntdll.dll".

Most of the answers here and elsewhere for similar problems seem to be because of 32/64 bit compatibility issues. I'm unable to figure out what might be going wrong here since the application was built using a 64-bit compiler. In the Qt Build and Run options, the device type is set to Desktop, and there are no other windows alternatives.

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: you might still be missing some dll.

Comment: On profiling with dependency walker on the server, I found the following error : "Second chance exception 0xC000007B (Unknown) occurred in "c:\windows\system32\NTDLL.DLL" at address 0x00007FF8B014C4E0.". However, when I profile on my laptop, it's still loading the ntdll.dll file from the system32 folder, but it seems to work fine with it.

Comment: Is it possible that this ntdll.dll differs between windows 7 and windows server 2012? If so, how can I get it to work?

Comment: The question of which this is marked as duplicate has a suggestion to install the Visual C++ Redistributable package on the target machine. I'll try this out, but it might need some time as this is a production server, and I'll need to go through a bunch of approvals before installing anything on that machine. If it works, I can probably consider this as a duplicate to that question.

Comment: there is a marked answer. try it first for diagnosis.